# SQL Server 2012 SSRS C# Web Service Error

Tags: c#, web-services, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I was using SQL Server 2008R2 with SSRS. In my c# project and based on examples from Microsoft's website I was able to output a PDF report. I switched to SQL Server 2012, setup the web service all over again with the same endpoint `http://localhost/ReportServer/reportexecution2005.asmx?wsdl`. 
I made sure SSRS for the 2008R2 wasn't running and that the 2012 was.

The error I'm receiving in my project during debug is:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: 
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices/LoadReport. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest() at 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize() at 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) at 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to update the web reference in the c# project itself. This is a context menu item as shown below:

[image: context menu] 
The error shows a mismatch in the web service definition, thus you can not use the web references generated for SQL server 2008.

Comment: Although, I've fixed this issue and intended to report my findings back here, I simply forgot. Updating the web reference tho I believe wasn't the issue the fix, however, I don't remember. Its worth a try to whom ever comes up with this same issue.

Comment: Another possibility is SSRS permissions/setup are not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have to add the System.Web.Services dll reference.[image]